# Gemfire Subscription does not work on distributed environment

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

I setup a cluster Gemfire environment with 2 locators and 3 nodes. I would like to use it as a publisher/subscription solution. I create a cache-listener in the Java application and it works well(logging) when I insert an item into a region. However, then I start a gfsh window to insert an item, the java listerner dose not work. My configuration is below:

```
 <gfe:client-cache id="client-cache" pool-name="my-pool" properties-ref="gemfire-props"/>
 <gfe:pool id="my-pool" subscription-enabled="true">
         <gfe:locator host="10.151.134.111" port="10334" /> 
    </gfe:pool>
    <gfe:client-region id="Test" data-policy="EMPTY" cache-ref="client-cache">
         <gfe:cache-listener> 
           <bean class="Test.util.LoggingCacheListener"/> 
        </gfe:cache-listener>       
    </gfe:client-region>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need data-policy=NORMAL (or something other than EMPTY) for this to work. See [DataPolicy](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/latest/javadocs/japi/com/gemstone/gemfire/cache/DataPolicy.html) for more details. The client listener will not fire because data is never replicated to the client cache, so there is no state change. With data-policy=EMPTY, the listener will fire only if a put is executed by the client.

Comment: I set it as NORMAL, but the listener does not fire against remote put. Any special configuration on server side?